# Is Casey Neistat's video of himself flying under a drone genuine?

Tags: consumer-products, sport, video

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At3xcj-pTjg) a vlogger shows off themselves flying, doing jumps and snowboarding uphill by being attached to a large drone.

Was he effectively being dragged and lifted by the drone?

Comment: Did you [watch the other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyUrqZBs2XA) about the drone?

Comment: @Bakuriu A "making of" video made by the same people should perhaps itself be treated with some degree of skepticism.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, I didn't say that it is a proof of anything, however it makes some clear statements about the methodology used to produce the original video, which are quite reasonable and explain a few things that might look suspicious otherwise. I believe, knowing the parties involved and their history, I really don't see a good reason to be highly skeptic... if the OP has some doubt due to a *specific thing* in the video, he should clarify exactly, but overall the video is surely plausible and I find the explanations reasonable and believable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what evidence you would need, but watch [the rebuttal video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyUrqZBs2XA) Bakuriu linked to, made by the team who produced the original, and with commentary listing the technical specifications (starting around 1:40)

Importantly - it has about 108 horsepower (2:20 seconds in) - which is ample to lift an individual. In fact it was massively overpowered specifically so it could cope with a failure of a motor or propeller.

[This site](http://www.dronesglobe.com/guide/heavy-lift-drones/) lists some drones capable of carrying up to 20kg - and they are nowhere near the size or power of this one.